# How to send token to MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet

I'd like to understand how can I send my MCO to MyEtherWallet, I've just tried to send 1 from Bittrex using as withdrawal address the one of the wallet but after 2 hours it looks like it the transaction has been done on Bittrex but not sign of life from MyEtherWallet.

Could the waiting time be longer? Do I have to spend some Gas from Bittrex (isn't it automatic)?

Comment: Have you already added the token to your custom tokens? And do you see the transaction in etherscan?